# What does $variable = some_function(arg1, arg2) == 'string'; mean in php?

Tags: php, variables

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but I have no idea what to search to find the answer.

I'm presuming it means $variable = returned value or string if function doesn't return a value but I'd like clarification.

Thanks

Comment: If the return value of the function is equal to the string the variable gets assigned with TRUE otherwise FALSE.

Comment: By the way, the behaviour you describe and are perhaps looking for, is the `ternary operator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement can best be understood by breaking it down:

```
some_function(arg1, arg2)
```

The function is executed first, and returns some value. Note that even if the function contains no `return` statement, it will return a value, in that case, the value `null`.

```
== 'string'
```

The value returned is compared against the string value `'string'`. Note that PHP's comparison operator may perform "type juggling", so other values such as integer 0 are considered equal to this string. This will give you a result of either `true` or `false`.

```
$variable =
```

The result of the comparison (not the function call) is stored in `$variable`.

So after the statement, `$variable` will contain `true` if the function returned something considered equal to `'string'`, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: An alternative way of looking at it is by adding brackets. The statement is the equivalent of `$variable = (some_function($arg1, $arg2) == 'string');`

Answer (score 1):

This will check whether the value returned by the function `some_function()` is equal to value   `string` (don't get confused with **string** data type) or not and assign `true` or `false` to `$variable`, based on the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$a = "Hello ";
$b = "World";

if ($result = some_function($a, $b) == "Hello World") {
    echo "Yep it matched" . "<br/>";
    // In True or false

    if ($result == TRUE) {   
        echo "True matched";
    }

} 

else
{
    echo "Nope, it doesn't matched" . "<br/>";

    if ($result == FALSE) {
        echo "False failed";
    }

}

function some_function($a, $b)
{
    $new = $a . $b;
    return $new;
}

?>
```

Output :

```
Yep it matched
True matched
```

**Explanation :**

1. `some_function($a, $b)` in the `if` condition calls the function `some_function($a, $b)` and the returned value will be saved in the place of `some_function($a, $b)`.
2. So, based on our example `some_function($a, $b)` in the if statement will have `Hello World` which was returned from the `some_function($a, $b)` function (i.e return $new).
3. Now, it checks in the statement

   ```
   if ($result = some_function($a, $b) == "Hello World") {
   ```
4. Our `some_function($a, $b`) has "Hello World" & it compares with the String "Hello World" which is in the right side. (i.e this part == "Hello World")
5. If it matches then, `$result` will have value `TRUE` and it executes what's in the if block.
6. If it doesn't matches, `$result` will have value `FALSE`and then it goes to `else` block and executes what's in the `else` block.

Suppose, if

```
  $a = "Good ";
  $b = "Night ";
```

then $a & $b passed as a parameter in `some_function($a, $b)` which will return `Good Night`.

And the returned value (in this case `Good Night`), will be stored in the place of `some_function($a, $b)` in the if condition.

Our `some_function($a, $b`) has `Good Night` & it compares with the String "Hello World" which is in the right side. (i.e this part == "Hello World")

If it matches, $result will be set to `TRUE` if not set to `FALSE`.

Here, it will fail since it won't match. So, it will output as,

```
Nope, it doesn't matched
False failed
```

If it matched, then it will print as

```
Yep it matched
True matched
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, just adds even more complexity to the statement by building it into an `if` (and leaving the assigned variable unused).

Comment: Sorry, but now it just seems even more complex. I understand what it does, but that's because I already know what the original statement does; if I didn't, I don't think this example would help.

Comment: Thanks, now i've added the complete explanation.

Comment: Your explanation is incorrect. $result will never hold 'Hello world', only true or false, because the comparison happens before the assignment.